# What does the "Document Assembly" permission for PDFs mean?

Tags: permissions, pdf, encryption, adobe-acrobat

One of the built-in PDF permissions that can be set or unset with an Owner Password using a tool like Adobe Acrobat or `qpdf` is the Document Assembly restriction:

[image]

All other PDF permissions protected by the Owner Password seem self-explanatory enough, but the meaning of Document Assembly is a little ambiguous. What exactly does disabling Document Assembly on a PDF prevent against?

Answer (score 1):

Document assembly means that you can use the document either as part of another document (inserting pages) or that you can add/insert pages (or other documents) to your document.